# How can I change the default folder location that nautilus opens?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, default

The default is that clicking on the folder in the unity dock opens the home directory.

Since there are shortcuts for all the sub-folders of the home directory in the sidebar already, I'd prefer the default directory to move to a different location (`~/Documents`).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be sure, you mean this icon here?

[image]

If yes, edit the file `/usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop` and alter the line (#4):

```
Exec=nautilus %U
```

to

```
Exec=nautilus /your/path/
```

and save the file. But notice, it will be system wide.

Comment: Yes, I do mean the folder in the dock. Mine has a house in it. But changing that `nautilus-home.desktop` did not do anything. I did restart nautilus after applying the change.

Comment: Can you post the output of this command `gsettings list-recursively com.canonical.Unity.Launcher` please?

Comment: `com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorite-migration '3.2.10'
com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites ['nautilus.desktop', 'gnome-terminal.desktop', 'geany.desktop', 'chromium-browser.desktop', 'thunderbird.desktop', 'polly.desktop', 'banshee.desktop', 'xpad.desktop', 'keepassx.desktop']
`

Comment: Ok, so I just had to edit `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop`. Alright! It works now :P

Comment: FYI: `gsettings list-recursively com.canonical.Unity.Launcher` lists all your starter shortcuts and what's being executed.

Comment: Mmmh. An unpleasant side-effect now is that once I open downloaded files via chromium in nautilus - nautilus will open two windows: one in the download location and one in the default directory

Comment: This does not work in Ubuntu 18.10.